# Indentify invalid domains in proxy addresses (comparing arrays)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to write a Powershell script, which will browse through all proxyAddresses of all Active Directory users and identify if there are users with any domains e.g. valid domains are: "contoso.com", "contoso.com.au" and "test.com". If a user has proxyAddress as "SMTP:testuser@contoso.com, smtp:testuser@contoso123.com", the script should give an error that testuser has an email address with invalid domain.

Can someone please assist?

Thanks in advance,
Ravi

Comment: what have you tried? what did not work as expected? PLEASE, show your code ... and wrap it in formatting markers to make it easy to read. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

Just to post answer for this one, I managed to write the solution.

Here is the working script:

```
$validDomains = @("contoso.com", "contoso.com.au","test.com")
$users = Get-Content "UserstoCheck.csv"
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $userChecking = get-aduser $user -Properties ProxyAddresses | select samAccountName, ProxyAddresses    
    foreach ($ProxyAddress in $UserChecking.ProxyAddresses) {           
        if (($validDomains -notcontains ($ProxyAddress -split '@')[1]) -and ($ProxyAddress -notlike "X500:*") -and ($ProxyAddress -notlike "X400:*") ) {            
               Write-Host " $user has invalid ProxyAddress as $ProxyAddress"            
        }
    }
}
```